# minimal generating set for modules over quotient ring of polynomial ring

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, modules, ideals

Let $R=\frac{k[X_1,\ldots,X_n]}{I}$, where $k$ is a field and $I$ is an ideal. Let $M$ be a finitely generated module over $R$. I would like to compute a minimal generating set for $M$. As $R$ is not a polynomial ring, Quillen-Suslin cannot be applied here. However I would like to know whether there are any special cases in which mingen can be computed, algorithmically?

In particular, I am more interested in the following situation:

$I$ is a principal ideal. By some other calculations, I know that $M$ is generated by $r$ generators, which satisfy 1 relation. i.e. $syz(M)$ is a cyclic module. In the language of computational algebra system, $M$ is a right module on $r$ generators satisfying 1 relation.

By some other theory I know that $M$ is minimally generated by $r-1$ generators. Is there any way to compute these $r-1$ generators?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not think these can be easy in general. If we assume that $I$ is prime, then the relation vector $(a_1,\ldots,a_r)$ is completable, that is it is the first row of a non-singular matrix under your hypothesis. Over polynomial rings, if $r\geq 3$, this vector can be transformed to $(1,0,\ldots,0)$ by row operations and so may be calculated (still difficult). But in $R$, this is generally not true and so transforming this to the above simple one (which is essentially the only way to find $r-1$ generators) may be next to impossible, even if theoretically possible.

Comment: Dear Mohan, Thanks for the comment. 
I know its very difficult to get the generators in general. As it is difficult to talk about unimodularity in this type of rings.
But I was wondering if there are some known results in special cases, like, if syz is a cyclic. This gives a much simpler resolution! Also if I can put some restrictions on $I$, like principal ideal or so!